# SQL Server - Delete older datetime entries if date appears more than once

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, duplicates

I have a table that will sometimes have duplicate entries for the same day but different contain a different insert_time based on when the data was ingested into the database. I am looking for a way to remove earlier entries that contain the same date but an earlier time if a record is inserted more than once on that day.

What I have:

```
    ID  insert_time
1   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
2   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
3   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
1   2020-04-28 12:13:04.923
2   2020-04-28 12:13:04.923
3   2020-04-28 12:13:04.923
1   2020-04-28 13:13:04.923
2   2020-04-28 13:13:04.923
1   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
2   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
3   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
```

What I want:

```
ID  insert_time
1   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
2   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
3   2020-04-26 04:23:04.923
3   2020-04-28 12:13:04.923
1   2020-04-28 13:13:04.923
2   2020-04-28 13:13:04.923
1   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
2   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
3   2020-04-29 10:16:03.876
```

The current query I'm working on is:

```
SELECT * FROM my_table
WHERE insert_time
   IN (SELECT MIN(insert_time)
       FROM my_table GROUP BY [id])
```

but it only returns records with the earliest insert_time in the entire table. I'm stuck trying to figure out how to return rows that have more than one insert_time of the same date and then selecting the earlier of them.

Comment: `ID` isn't unique? How do you uniquely identify a row?

Comment: @AaronBertrand But `ID` does appear to be unique on a given day.

Comment: Do you want to *delete* the other rows, or just prevent them from showing up in the result? Is `ID` related to `insert_time` in any way (e.g. is the highest `ID` on a given day also the latest row)?

Comment: @Tim that's not true, the source has multiple rows from 4/28 with the same `ID`.

Comment: @Aaron, Tim is correct and the ID is unique for the given day. Records are ingested from a CSV file and will have multiple entries over different days. To clarify my question, the file has been ingested multiple times on the same day but I want to keep the records from the later ingestion time on the same day.

Comment: The source data doesn't seem to agree (multiple rows for `ID = 1`, for example, on 4/28). In any case, ideally, you also have some way to uniquely identify a row (and if `ID` can't do that, it's a bad name). I'd agree that's what you _want_ but it's not what you _have_.

Comment: @Aaron I didn't finish the sentence properly.  I should have said: ID appears to be unique per day _in the expected output_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use exists logic here:

```sql
DELETE
FROM my_table t1
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM my_table t2
              WHERE t2.ID = t1.ID AND
                    CONVERT(date, t2.insert_time) =
                    CONVERT(date, t1.insert_time) AND
                    t2.insert_time > t1.insert_time);
```

Read in plain English, the above query says to delete a record for which we can find another record with the same `ID`, same date, but a *later* timestamp.

Comment: Hi Tim, thanks for the response this seems to be working without issue. I'm just verifying the result and will accept your answer shortly.

Answer (score 1):

I prefer to use window functions for this simply because they scale linearly. With self-joins you get exponential effects.

```
;WITH cte AS 
(
  SELECT ID, insert_time, rn = ROW_NUMBER() OVER 
    (PARTITION BY ID, CONVERT(date, insert_time) 
     ORDER BY insert_time DESC)
  FROM dbo.source_table
)
SELECT ID, insert_time 
  FROM cte WHERE rn = 1
  ORDER BY insert_time, ID;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method would work if you treated it as a correlated clause:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM my_table t
WHERE t.insert_time = (SELECT MIN(t2.insert_time)
                       FROM my_table t2
                       WHERE t2.id = t.id AND
                             CONVERT(DATE, t2.insert_time) = CONVERT(DATE, t.insert_time)
                      );
```